# How to make the log written only to a file in python?

Tags: python, python-logging

I need the logger requests to be written only to a file and not to pollute the console
My code:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

_log_format = f"[%(asctime)s] %(message)s"

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('logs/db.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(_log_format))
logger = logging.getLogger('peewee')
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

All requests are written both to the file and to the screen, and I did not understand how to make it so that the output is only to the file, help
I tried like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='[%(asctime)s] %(message)s',
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler('logs/db.log')
    ]
)
```

It doesn't work as I need and it also writes all other logs and I only need to write peewee log

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please research your questions thoroughly and review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before creating a new post. Your question has already been answered here: [python logging only to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711475/python-logging-only-to-file)

Comment: I'm not a robot to find this information so quickly and read these manuals as a nerd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you calling `logging.basicConfig`? The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) **clearly states**:

> Does basic configuration for the logging system by creating a StreamHandler with a default Formatter and adding it to the root logger.

Just set up your logger without calling basicconfig.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('peewee')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('/tmp/foo.log'))

logger.info('Test')
```

"Test" is written to /tmp/foo.log and not printed.

Please read the manuals before posting.